# Add more semantic highlighting to Monaco Editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Here is code of a Monaco Editor (0.21.0) instance:

[image]

and here is VS Code

[image]

As you can tell, the VS Code is more defined by coloring in the `.log`, the parameters, the operator `+` and more. How do I get the top version of Monaco Editor to colorize like how VS Code has it?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the ask here. Are you saying how you can change the colouring? If yes, take a look at https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html. But if you're asking how you can get a particular VS Code theme, I'm not sure.